# Doctrine2 move immutable fields into separate class

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I need move some immutable fields into separate class, but I don't really want to use "join", because I need all data together every time.

Is any way to have some entity attributes as classes that mapped into same table?

Something like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    ...

    /**
     * @var Address
     * @ORM\... ??
     */
    protected $address
}

/**
 * @ORM\ValueObject ??
 */
class Address {
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="address_zipcode", length=12)
     */
    protected $zipcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="address_country_iso", length=3)
     */
    protected $countryIso;
    ...
}
```

And table structure would be:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `address_zipcode` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    `address_country_iso` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Probably [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440879/doctrine-2-value-objects) you can find answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine introduced the concept of value objects in version `2.x`.

The name for new attributes/annotations are `Embeddable` and `Embedded`. The first for mark the Value Object class, and the second for actual injecting Value Object into the parent Entity.

Here is updated code snippet from my original question:

```php
/** @ORM\Entity */
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    ...

    /** @ORM\Embedded(class="Address", columnPrefix="address") */
    protected $address
}

/** @ORM\Embeddable */
class Address {
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="address_zipcode", length=12) */
    protected $zipcode;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="address_country_iso", length=3) */
    protected $countryIso;
    ...
}
```

Resources:

- https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.17/tutorials/embeddables.html

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about is called Value Objects.

There was an open issue in there Jira [DDC-93](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-93) to add support. It's current marked as Resolved in version 2.5, which was just released in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

If you whant store object without join:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="adress", type="object")
 */
```

It will serialize/deserialize automatically to a textfield

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html

And add setter with type you whant to store

```
public function setAdress(Address $adress)
{
    $this->adress = $adress;

    return $this;
}
```

Adress class won't need any @ORM annotations

Answer (score 0):

It'll be just like that you said something like.

Add @PreUpdate and @PostLoad hook into `User`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    ...

    /**
     * @var Address
     * (NOTE: no @ORM annotation here)
     */
    protected $address

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $addressZipCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $addressCountryIso;

    public function setAddress(Address $address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     *
     * set $addressZipCode and $addressCountryInfo when this object is to
     * save so that doctrine can easily save these scalar values
     */
    public function extractAddress()
    {
        $this->addressZipCode = $this->address->getZipCode();
        $this->addressCountryIso = $this->address->getAddressCountryIso();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     *
     * When the row is hydrated into this class,
     * $address is not set because that isn't mapped.
     * so simply, map it manually
     */
    public function packAddress()
    {
        $this->address = new Address();
        $this->address->setZipCode($this->addressZipCode);
        $this->address->setCountryIs($this->addressCountryIso);
    }
}
```